# Como fazer para quando a pessoa tirar o mouse de cima diminuir o tamanho só com o css

Tags: css, eventos, animação

Quero saber se tem como quando você tirar o mouse de cima de uma div ele diminuir o tamanho somente com o css exemplo: (:hover)

```css
.post:hover {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    animation-name: aumentar;
    animation: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Acho que só com Javascript

Comment: Vc quer que na hora do hover o elemento diminua e que fique pequeno mesmo depois que vc tirar o mouse de cima dele e fique assim pra sempre eh isso?

Comment: Opa eu consigo diminuir normalmente quando a pessoa tira o mouse, é que eu fiz uma animação de diminuir e eu queria aplicar ela quando só a pessoa tirasse o mouse de cima

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo aumenta a `div` quando o mouse está em cima, e volta ao tamanho original quando o mouse sai da `div`.

```css
.post{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#dddddd;  
  transition-duration:1s;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%
}

.post:hover{
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="post"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-class `:hover` é um tipo de selector que acontece apenas quando o mouse está sobre o elemento especificado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  
    .post {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .post:hover {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="post"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Este exemplo simples em cima mostra perfeitamente o que eu acabei de falar, `:hover` só vai acontece quando mouse estiver em cima do elemento então caso você coloque o mouse mais o menos `190px` no eixo x e `5px` no eixo y, por exemplo, você vera que a `div` vai ficar meio que piscando isso por causa que a `div` foi definida como `width: 200px` e `height: 200px` e quando passar o mouse por cima vai ficar `width: 100px` e `height: 100px`, mas ao mesmo tempo que eu movo o mouse por cima eu também estou tirando então ele fica neste estado desagradável.

Neste caso você poderia usar *JavaScript*, mas como você disse.

> somente com o css

Então você teria que usar o exemplo de cima, mas apenas uma amostra de como seria com o *JavaScript*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  
    .post {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="post"></div>
  
<script>

var div = window.document.querySelector(".post");

div.addEventListener("mouseout", saiu);

function saiu() {

  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Bem simples, sem bug, sem nada, funcionando perfeitamente então fique avontade de escolher um dos de cima :).

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples diminuir o tamanho com hover. É só você dizer o tamanho dela normal como no exemplo1 e depois diminuir esse tamanho no exemplo1:hover.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .exemplo1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    animation: 1s;
    }
   .exemplo1:hover {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    animation: 1s;
    }
  
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="exemplo1">
    <p>exemplo 1</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: está bugado quando o mouse está naquele espaço dos 40px entre os "110px e 150px"

Comment: Está bugado kkkkk ai morri!